# How to login on Gmail without the phone?

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

My phone was stolen, I'm trying to login to Gmail, but since Gmail sends a code when you log in I can't get the code. I still know my password but it still asks for the code.

I tried my recovery mail but it says:

> There's no Google account with the info that you provided.

But I provided the right info. Is it still possible to retrieve my account?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use your backup...

> [image]
>
> **[https://support.google.com/accounts/](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en&ref_topic=2954345)**
>
> [image: 2]
>
> **[https://support.google.com/accounts/](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538)**